# Python pip install mysql-connector-python 2.0.1 fails

Tags: python, mysql, django

In developing a Django application, I used the following command to install MySQL (python3):

```
(Venv)$ pip3 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

The installation was sucessful, and `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` shows that `mysql-connector-python==2.0.1` was installed.

However, in the production environment, `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` produced the following error message.

```
Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector-python==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: That version doesn't appear to be available from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python). Try changing the version to `2.0.2` in your requirements file.

Comment: Still error: `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python==2.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))`,  `No distributions at all found for mysql-connector-python==2.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))`

Comment: These commands worked for me: `pip3 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python` and   `pip3 install mysql-connector-python==2.0.2 --allow-external mysql-connector-python`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I used for development installation. I just wondered why `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` didn't work.

Comment: maybe it was wrongly written in requirements.txt or `--allow-external mysql-connector-python` was missing from there.

Answer (score 4):

There is an outstanding bug with the way it is packaged on PIP.
here are the details: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76063

You can use following commands to install mysql-connector as mentioned on same link :

```
wget https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.3.zip
unzip mysql-connector-python-2.0.3.zip
cd mysql-connector-python-2.0.3
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

pip can not install mysql-python-connector due to an error on the part of its package maintainers. [Here is the relevant issue filed against that package's bug tracker.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76063) Although technically it should be installable with

`pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python --allow-unverified mysql-connector-python  mysql-connector-python`

this does not work if the package maintainers fail to [correctly register the external URLs to PyPI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0438/#api-for-submitting-external-distribution-urls).

Note that [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) appears to be a complete drop-in replacement, as a pure-Python MySQL driver that implements the Python DB API 2.0 specification. Additionally, PyMySQL appears to be actively maintained, uploaded to PyPI (as opposed to hosted on external URLs), and is under the more generous MIT license (as opposed to the GPLv2 license).

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you do not want to install manually:

`sudo pip3 install --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/2.0.4 mysql-connector-python`

Works for me on Debian Jessie.